# Ordering an array of dates from newest to oldest in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

Im new to Javascript and I'm looking for a way to order an array of dates (newest to oldest). I was going to right up my own function, but wanted to check if there was a built-in way or better way to do it in Javascript.

Comment: There is no better way than using `sort` and writing your comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Array.sort()` method and pass it a function which compares the `getTime()` value of the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `Date` [object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), and with the function `UTC()` or `getTime()` you will get a value which can be sorted easily and transferred back to a `Date` object. Store the Date's in an array and use `Array.sort()` and first define your sort function:

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Source: [www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

So something like:

```
var dates = [...some dates...];
dates.sort(function(a, b){return a.getTime() - b.getTime()});
```

**Edit**: since `UTC()` gives a `string` and `getTime()` an `int`, `getTime()` would be better.